# PHP Fatal error: Class 'Curl' not found with PHP 5.5

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to run this code:

```
<?php 

    $url = 'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/comments';
    $data = array("site" => 'graphicdesign', "key" => "W*i*e*V*M*N*F*y*b*t*R*((", "filter" => "!2.5sIHWRkCVWC)rFPY_1P", "order" => "desc", "sort" => "creation");

    $httpresponse = (new Curl)->exec($url . '?' . http_build_query($data), [CURLOPT_ENCODING => 'gzip']); //Line 6

    $obj = json_decode($httpresponse);
    $response = $obj->{'items'};
```

However, it fails with this error:

```
$ php getcomments.php 
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Curl' not found in /home/me/gdcommentgetter/getcomments.php on line 6
```

From [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20256042/why-does-this-php-code-run-on-one-machine-and-fail-on-another), I though it might be a problem with my PHP version - class member access on instantiation `((new Object)->method())` [wasn't available until PHP 5.4.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20256057/1849664)

`php --version`, though, shows that I'm on a version > 5.4:

```
$ php --version
PHP 5.5.7-1+sury.org~precise+1 (cli) (built: Dec 12 2013 21:48:51) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.3-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2013, by Zend Technologies
```

I've run `sudo apt-get install php5-curl`, as suggested many places, but it still fails with the same error. What's wrong?

Comment: Curl isn't a class, it's a library. Also, remove credentials from your post asap

Comment: Did you restart Apache after installing php-curl?

Comment: @AlmaDo There aren't any credentials in it. The filter isn't secret and the key has been censored (it isn't terribly secret either).

Comment: @JamesAnderson I have, and I'm running it from the command line anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://www.php.net/curl) there is no class `Curl`.

Perhaps you forgot to import some class of your own, or of another third-party vendor?

Answer (score 2):

You are probably using some third-party Curl library which provides the class.

Otherwise you need to use curl_init() and if you haven't got curl installed you need to install like so:

sudo apt-get install php5-curl

this is for Ubuntu machines only and some other distros probably

Answer (score 0):

Well there is no built it curl class in php but many devs have created their own wrapper around curl like https://github.com/sirfilip/curl/blob/master/Curl.php . The reason that it works on your server is because maybe you have installed some php lib on the server that you dont have it installed locally.